# Saving directory content to an array (bash)

Tags: arrays, bash, directory

I need to save content of two directories in an array to compare them later. Thats the solution i write:

```
DirContent()    
{
        #past '$1' directorys to 'directorys'
        local DIRECTORYS=`ls -l --time-style="long-iso" $1 | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $8}'`
        local CONTENT
        local i
        for DIR in $DIRECTORYS
        do
                i=+1
                CONTENT[i]=${DIR}
        done
        echo $CONTENT
}
```

Then when I try to print this array I get empty output. Both directories are not empty. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.
Thanks, Siery.

Comment: are you sure about `i=+1`? I think it should be `((i=i+1))`

Comment: Yes. You have right. 'i=+1' adds element to an array when '((1=i+1))' modify value. Probably next error i make was 'CONTENT[i]' not 'CONTENT[$i]'. But function still returns empty arrays, problem is somewhere else.

Comment: 1 = i+1 surely not, 1 can't be the LHS of an assignment. 1 is always 1.

Comment: Sorry, i misspell, it's 5 am in Europe :). *'((i=i+1))'

Comment: You know that 'print $8' will fail if you have blanks in filenames and the like? Can you exclude such patterns? Btw: If your ability to post questions is that much affected by the time, you should go to sleep and ask when fit again. And why don't you use `content=($(ls -l ... '{print $8}')` to create the array? to produce the array?

Comment: Yes, i was just thinking the same when i look at this code. That i can just write this function in two lines. Any ways, no, i don't know how to fix that problem you mention. I start learning bash 2 days ago. Can you help me with that? This is backup script so i cant know what files am i going to deal with.

Comment: Recommended reading: [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of this question is answered in the [one I marked as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494336/how-do-you-store-a-list-of-directories-into-an-array-in-bash-and-then-print-the). Here are a few more pointers:

- All uppercase variable names are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/3266847) as they are more likely to clash with environment variables.
- You assign to `DIRECTORYS` (should probably be "director**ies**") the output of a complicated command, which suffers from a few deficiencies:

  - Instead of backticks as in `` var=`command` ``, the syntax `var=$(command)` is [preferred](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).
  - `egrep` is [deprecated](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) and `grep -E` is preferred.
  - The grep and awk commands could be combined to `awk /^d/ '{ print $8 }'`.
  - There are better ways to get directories, for example `find`, but the output of `find` shouldn't be parsed either.
  - [You shouldn't process the output of `ls` programmatically](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): filenames can contain spaces, newlines, other special characters...
- `DIRECTORYS` is now just one long string, and you rely on [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) to iterate over it. Again, spaces in filenames will trip you up.
- `DIR` isn't declared `local`.
- To increase `i`, you'd use `(( ++i ))`.
- `CONTENT[i]=${DIR}` is actually okay: the `i` is automatically expanded here and doesn't have to be prepended by a `$`. Normally you'd want to [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) your variables like `"$dir"`, but in this case we happen to know that it won't be split any further as it already *is* the result of word splitting.
- Array indices start at zero and you're skipping zero. You should increase the counter *after* the assignment.
- Instead of using a counter, you can just append to an array with `content+=("$dir")`.
- To print the contents of an array, you'd use `echo "${CONTENT[@]}"`.

But *really*, what you should do instead of all this: a call `DirContent some_directory` is equivalent to `echo some_directory/*/`, and if you want that in an array, you'd just use

```
arr=(some_directory/*/)
```

instead of the whole function – this even works for weird filenames. And is much, much shorter.

If you have hidden directories (names starts with `.`), you can use `shopt -s dotglob` to include them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
        for((i=0;i<${#CONTENT[*]};i++))
        do
             echo ${CONTENT[$i]}
        done
```

instead of echo $CONTENT

Also these change are required

```
     ((i=+1))
     CONTENT[$i]=${DIR}
```

in your above code