# Populate an array with list of directories existing in a given path in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, listdir

I have a directory path where there are multiple files and directories.

I want to use basic bash script to create an array containing only list of directories.

Suppose I have a directory path:
`/my/directory/path/`

```
$ls /my/directory/path/
a.txt dirX b.txt dirY dirZ
```

Now I want to populate array named `arr[]` with only directories, i.e. `dirX`, `dirY` and `dirZ`.

Got one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494336/how-do-you-store-a-list-of-directories-into-an-array-in-bash-and-then-print-the) but its not that relevant with my requirement.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You mean the line `array=(*/)`? Seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(/my/directory/path/*/)    # This creates an array of the full paths to all subdirs
arr=("${arr[@]%/}")            # This removes the trailing slash on each item
arr=("${arr[@]##*/}")          # This removes the path prefix, leaving just the dir names
```

Unlike the `ls`-based answer, this will not get confused by directory names that contain spaces, wildcards, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Expanded globs include names that start with '.'

arr=()
for dir in /my/directory/path/*/ ; do
    dir2=${dir%/}       # Remove the trailing /
    dir3=${dir2##*/}    # Remove everything up to, and including, the last /
    arr+=( "$dir3" )
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
baseDir="/my/directory/path/"
readarray -d '' arr < <(find "${baseDir}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

Here the `find` command outputs all directories within the `baseDir`, then the `readarray` command puts these into an array names `arr`.

You can then work over the array with:

```
for directory in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "${directory}"
done
```

**Note**: This only works with bash version 4.4-alpha and above. (*See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357277/7371436) for more.*)